# SharedPreferences NullPointerException in DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, sharedpreferences, dialogfragment

I have some trouble working with SharedPreferences in DialogFragment. And I keep getting NullPointerException in line `sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);`.
Here is may basic code.

```
public class ADialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public ADialogFragment(int a) {
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
        if (a == 0) {
            saveToPref(0);
        } else if (a == 1) {
            saveToPref(1);
        } else saveToPref(2);
    }
    private void saveToPref(int itemInt) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(getString(R.string.item), itemInt);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: please learn fragments lifecycle ... you cennot get activity when fragment is not attached to it ...

Comment: can you post the stacktrace. it makes it easier for the rest to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `getActivity()` too early in fragment constructor and it returns null. A fragment is only attached to an activity in `onAttach()` or later in the fragment lifecycle.

Move the code that needs shared preferences to a later phase in the lifecycle.

Also note that fragments should not have constructors that take arguments. Use `setArguments()` to pass in parameters to fragments.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and informative answer. I`ll try your advices.

Answer (score 0):

The method getSharedPreferences is a method of the Context object, so just calling getSharedPreferences from a Fragment will not work.

So you need to do it like below

```
sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
```

Comment: And it still not working.

Comment: @Selvin : May be you are over smart and i am not.